# Getting a values from an array based on a sequential order

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach, iterator

Suppose I have an array like such:

```
var test_array = [0.1, 2.1, 0.7, 5.4, 3.2, 1.6];
```

I basically want to grab the first 2 values in the array, place them into 2 separate variables and then move on to the next step, like so:

```js
var test_array = [0.1, 2.1, 0.7, 5.4, 3.2, 1.6];
test_array.sort();
for (let i=0;i< test_array.length -1; i++) {
   var j = i + 1;
   var pt_one = test_array[i];
   var pt_two = test_array[j];
   console.log("pt_one = " + pt_one);
   console.log("pt_two = " + pt_two);
   
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Could the forEach() method be used somehow?

Comment: `forEach` might be a bit better, but not by much. Your current code is fine.

Comment: There's little need for the `j` variable, just write `test_array[i+1]`

Answer (score 1):

It may not be much better, but your length is incorrect anyways. I thought you might want to see two increments at a time:

```js
let test_array = [0.1, 2.1, 0.7, 5.4, 3.2, 1.6, 10, 100], pt_one, pt_two;
test_array.sort((a, b)=>a-b);
for(let i=0,n=1,l=test_array.length; i<l; i+=2,n+=2){
  pt_one = test_array[i]; pt_two = test_array[n];
  console.log('pt_one = '+pt_one); console.log('pt_two = '+pt_two);
}
```

I noticed you will have a problem with that sort, as well.

Comment: More concise, but not quite what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this using `forEach`:

```
test_array.forEach((n, i, arr) => {
  var [pt_one,pt_two] = test_array.slice((arr.length - i) * -1);
})
```

Comment: This is almost perfect except for the last iteration puts pt_one = 100; pt_two = undefined;